# How to use the PARFOR loop for image processing without loading all images together

Tags: matlab, image-processing, parfor

I want to use a parfor loop for image processing. I do operations on single images and stacks of images. To keep the use of memory low I want to prevent storing all images in memory.

I start with the cell structure variable **Imagepaths{}{}** that contains
paths for different images in a cell in cell structure. **function1** operates on all individual images and **function2** operates on a stack of images, combining them into a single new image.

For example: **Imagepaths{}{}** contains 12 cell. Each cell contains a 1x5 cell with the paths of the images. **function2** operates on such a 1x5 stack of images.

The following code i initially try to use but the variable Images{} gives an error for the PARFOR loop.

```
parfor l = 1:numel(Imagepaths)
    for k = 1:numel(Imagepaths{l})
        Image = imread(Imagepaths{l}{k});
        Images{k} = function1(Image)
    end
        Image2{l} = function2(Images)
end
```

I came with a the following solution, but the disadvantage is that it takes a lot of memory as all images are stored.

```
parfor l = 1:numel(Imagepaths)
    for k = 1:numel(Imagepaths{l})
        Image = imread(Imagepaths{l}{k});
        Images{l}{k} = function1(Image)
    end
end
parfor l = 1:numel(Imagepaths)
    Image2{l} = function2(Images{l})
end
```

Does somebody can mention a solution to preserve for storing all images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, you've got two forms of indexing for `Imagepaths` inside the `parfor` loop, and that prevents *slicing*, which is what you want. See [the doc](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html) for more on valid indexing forms for sliced variables. The easiest way to convince `parfor` that what you're doing is OK is to pull out a temporary array from `Imagepaths` using valid sliced indexing, and then operate on that.

The second problem I encountered is that your temporary array `Images` is used in a way that `parfor` thinks is order-dependent (which strictly speaking it could be, but I suspect in practice it is not). The simplest way to fix that is to assign a new empty `cell` array to `Images` on each iteration of the loop, like so:

```
parfor l = 1:numel(Imagepaths)
    tmp = Imagepaths{l}; %# sliced indexing
    Images = cell(1, numel(tmp)); %# force "Images" to be "temporary"
    for k = 1:numel(tmp)
        Image = imread(tmp{k});
        Images{k} = function1(Image)
    end
    Image2{l} = function2(Images)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually your solution, forcing "Images" to be temporary, is enough to get "parfor" working, I discovered. But using "tmp" also preserve to send unnecessary information to the different cores although it is not much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Edric, mentioning temporary arrays, the following code also works without using the temporary variable "tmp" for the image paths.

```
parfor l = 1:numel(Imagepaths)
    Images = cell(1, number(Imagepaths{l}));
    for k = 1:numel(Imagepaths{l})
        Image = imread(Imagepaths{l}{k});
        Images{k} = function1(Image)
    end
        Image2{l} = function2(Images)
end
```